# How can I manipulate HTML tags in PHP?

Tags: php, html, replace

I want to manipulate the following piece of code:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

The output should look like:

```
<ul>
  <li itemprop="ingredients">1</li>
  <li itemprop="ingredients">2</li>
  <li itemprop="ingredients">3</li>
  <li itemprop="ingredients">4</li>
</ul>
```

The replacement should just take place between the `<ul>` tags. How can I do that with PHP?

Comment: Is this a page you're generating yourself? One you're reading from a remote site and want to edit?

Comment: **The lazy way**: simple replace. **The hard way**: using regex. **The easy way**: using a proper html parser.

Comment: how u r creating this list ? php/jQuery ? and why dont u do in the php code or with JQuery attr()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace <li> tags between <ul> tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231240/replace-li-tags-between-ul-tags)

Comment: **instead of making a new question you should have edited your previous question**

Comment: Since the edit got re-edited: Note that the above code could just be an excerpt, we do not know if there are more `<li>`s that should not be replaced. E.g. under `<ol>`.

Comment: @andrewsi no this is wordpress

Comment: @Hamza Merhaba burada verilen cevaplarla bir türlü yapamadım. Doğru kodu bulamadım bir türlü. Ul lerin altındaki li leri replace edebileceğim bir kod biliyor musun.

Comment: @user2682277 Euhm have you checked my profile ? I mentioned the languages I can speak, the one you're using isn't in the list. Anyways, you should be writing english on the main SO site.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string manipulation functions, such as `str_replace` :

```
$output = str_replace("<li", "<li itemprop=\"ingredients\"", $output);
```

This would replace `<li` by `<li itemprop="ingredients"`

Comment: That would replace all `<li`s even those under `<ol>` for instance. We don't know the whole code.

Comment: REGEX then. Something like `#<ul>[ ]*<li(.*)>#`... Really not my thing :p Anyway, that's definitely a job for Javascript.

Comment: @John WHS this will replace all <li> on the page. But I want to replace just which is under the <ol>

Comment: (see my previous answer)

Comment: @John WHS Smith this code is working: $( "ul > li" ).attr({ itemprob: "ingredients", }); but this not working google bot. Google bot could not see replaced version.

Comment: Javascript is executed by the client, so bots won't. You need to edit the content on the server side if you want bots to see the changes (PHP).

Comment: @John WHS Smith do you know how can i do that in php?

Comment: By reading all the answers that were **already** given to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should read more about the [php str_replace function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

The solution is:

```
$output = str_replace("<li>", "<li itemprop=\"ingredients\">", $output);
```

Comment: @Italy Thank you. But this code will replace all <li> on the page But I want to replace just which is under the <ul>

Comment: @user2682277 : What's special about this UL? You're not going to locate it specifically on search & replace functions if it's just like any other list on this page. Anyhow, if you're the one who's generating this page, then write this list to a temporary `variable`, enter this variable to the `str_replace` function, and then concatenate the temporary variable to the $output.

Comment: I did it this code $( "ul > li" ).attr({
  itemprob: "ingredients",
});

Comment: @user2682277 Okay that's a nice *client-side* code. PHP is a *server-side* coding language and that's what you've asked.

Comment: @user2682277 I need to server-side coding but i can not do that.